# How to handle Out of Memory error when loading single Bitmap from Camera

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, xamarin.android, out-of-memory

My question is how to handle an Out of Memory error when decoding a byte array into a bitmap so I can do a rotation on it.  My code is as follows and before you say its a duplicate, I have tried using BitmapFactory.Options and setting the sample size to 2.  However the quality loss was far too bad to be acceptable.  Also it appears to only be happening on one device so maybe its a one off thing, however I'm inclined to believe if it affects one, there will be 25 more like it later.  Also this is happening on the FIRST photo taken and this is the only work that this activity does with regards to bitmaps.   And while I'm working in Monodroid, Java answers are welcome too as I can usually translate them to C# fairly easily.

```
public void GotImage(byte[] image)
    {
        try
        {
            Android.Graphics.Bitmap thePicture = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(image, 0, image.Length);
            Array.Clear(image, 0, image.Length);
            image = null;
            GC.Collect();
            Android.Graphics.Matrix m = new Android.Graphics.Matrix();
            m.PostRotate(90);
            Android.Graphics.Bitmap rotatedPicture = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(thePicture, 0, 0, thePicture.Width, thePicture.Height, m, true);
            thePicture.Dispose();
            thePicture = null;
            GC.Collect();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                rotatedPicture.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
                image = ms.ToArray();
            }
            rotatedPicture.Dispose();
            rotatedPicture = null;
            GC.Collect();

            listOfImages.Add(image);
            storeButton.Text = "  Store " + listOfImages.Count + " Pages  ";
            storeButton.Enabled = true;
            takePicButton.Enabled = true;
            gotImage = false;
            cameraPreviewArea.camera.StartPreview();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialog.SetTitle("Error Taking Picture");
            alertDialog.SetMessage(ex.ToString());
            alertDialog.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate { });
            alertDialog.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a first step, I'd try to help the GC out by splitting this up into multiple methods(decode/rotate/compress), allowing each step's transitional bitmap/array to go out of scope. One method with `GC.Collect()` appearing three times freaks me out for some reason.

Comment: try using the [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html) methods. you can get a thumbnail from it and it might use a better algorithm for scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a long day of learning, I discovered a fix/workaround.  This involved setting the resolution of the picture being taken by the camera before the picture was taken instead of trying to scale it after the fact.  I also set the option in settings for the user to try different resolutions till they get one that works best for them.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
parameters.SetPictureSize(parameters.SupportedPictureSizes[parameters.SupportedPictureSizes.Count - 1].Width,
                    parameters.SupportedPictureSizes[parameters.SupportedPictureSizes.Count - 1].Height);
camera.SetParameters(parameters);
camera.StartPreview();
```

Answer (score 0):

What's `rotatedPicture.Dispose()`? Does this just set the reference to null? The best and quickest way to get rid of a Bitmap's memory is via the [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) method.

Comment: Calling Dispose() should be doing everything that recycle() does, but I might also try recycle to see what that results with.  As a heads up, I've just solved this issue and a detailed solution wiil be forthcoming.